# How to reuse a loading indicator in next.js routes?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Next.js allows me to [define a loading indicator](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/loading-ui) by placing it in a file named `loading.js` next to the component that has the route. How can I reuse the same loading indicator on multiple routes?

So far, I've moved it to its own file, say `Loading.js`:

```js
export default function LoadingWithSpinner() {
  return (
    <div>
        <!-- SVG spinner animation goes here -->
        <!-- screen reader specific loading note goes here -->
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then I define my `loading.js` like this:

```js
import LoadingWithSpinner from '@/components/Loading';

export default function loading() {
  return LoadingWithSpinner();
}
```

This works, but I am wondering if there is an easier way to point all loading indicators to that component without having to sprinkle these `loading.js` files throughout the code base. Even if it's just 5 lines, I'd rather DRY them up.

How to share a loading indicator between routes in next.js?

Comment: The doc says "it'll wrap the [...] file and any children below in a `<Suspense>` boundary", so I guess if you place the file in the root `app/` folder, it will be applied to all components and sub-components of your app pages.

Comment: you can also group routes: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/defining-routes